# Google spreadsheet api batchupdate using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, gspread

I am trying to update multiple cell values using batchupdate. But giving me below error

**My code:**

```
import gspread

gc = gspread.service_account(filename='gdrive_cred.json')
sh = gc.open('SmartStraddle').sheet1

stock_name = "NIFTY50"
stock_price = 15000

batch_update_values = {
    'value_input_option': 'USER_ENTERED',
    'data': [
        {
            'range': "A1",
            'values': [stock_name]
        },
        {
            'range': "B2",
            'values': [stock_price]
        }
    ],
}

sh.batch_update(batch_update_values)
```

**Error Message:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "*\interactiveshell.py", line 3433, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-2-028b1369fa03>", line 23, in <module>
    sh.batch_update(batch_update_values)
  File "*\utils.py", line 702, in wrapper
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "*\worksheet.py", line 1152, in batch_update
    data = [
           ^
  File "*\worksheet.py", line 1153, in <listcomp>
    dict(vr, range=absolute_range_name(self.title, vr["range"])) for vr in data
                                                   ~~^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: string indices must be integers, not 'str'
```

I am following [this](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/batchUpdate) google documentation, but not sure how to construct `data': []`  field correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guessed that you wanted to use [batch_update(data, **kwargs)](https://docs.gspread.org/en/v5.7.0/api/models/worksheet.html#gspread.worksheet.Worksheet.batch_update).

#### Modification points:

- When I saw the document of [batch_update(data, **kwargs)](https://docs.gspread.org/en/v5.7.0/api/models/worksheet.html#gspread.worksheet.Worksheet.batch_update), it seems that the argument of `data` is as follows.

  ```
    batch_update_values = [
        {"range": "A1", "values": [[stock_name]]},
        {"range": "B2", "values": [[stock_price]]},
    ]
  ```
- `value_input_option` is required to be put as an argument.

When these points are reflected in your script, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

##### From:

```
batch_update_values = {
    'value_input_option': 'USER_ENTERED',
    'data': [
        {
            'range': "A1",
            'values': [stock_name]
        },
        {
            'range': "B2",
            'values': [stock_price]
        }
    ],
}

sh.batch_update(batch_update_values)
```

##### To:

```
batch_update_values = [
    {"range": "A1", "values": [[stock_name]]},
    {"range": "B2", "values": [[stock_price]]},
]
sh.batch_update(batch_update_values, value_input_option="USER_ENTERED")
```

- When this modified script is run, the values of `NIFTY50` and `15000` are put to the cells "A2" and "B2", respectively.

#### Reference:

- [batch_update(data, **kwargs)](https://docs.gspread.org/en/v5.7.0/api/models/worksheet.html#gspread.worksheet.Worksheet.batch_update)